# Mudar Largura de um Modal

Tags: html5, twitter-bootstrap, modal, bootstrap-4

Olá, ao tentar aumentar a largura de um modal em bootstrap 4, tentei alterar a largura do modal-lg  através de css como vi no stack overflow inglês. No entanto, já tentei o mesmo código e não consigo fazer com que o modal-lg passe dos 800px predefinidos para uma medida costumizada. O código usado é o seguinte:

```
.modal-lg{
max-width:80% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para funcionar vc tem que colocar o estilo customizado do CSS dentro do *breacking point*! Se te interessar aqui tem um referencia na documentação oficial, porem o tamanho default do `modal-lg` é 800px e nao 80% da largura em telas grandes... https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#optional-sizes

Veja o exemplo como fica nesse exemplo, repare que eu tive que colocar a regra da largura do `modal` dentro do *media query* correto  `@media (min-width: 992px) { .modal-lg {css} }`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<style>
    @media (min-width: 992px) {
        .modal-lg {
            max-width: 80%;
        }
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    
    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ajudou muito. Só alterei o css para `.modal-lg{ min-width:80%;}` e funcionou direto obrigado.

Comment: @JoãoMartins boa, que bom que resolveu então´.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode adicionar uma classe `modal-long` onde a classe `modal-dialog` está.

```css
.modal-long {
  width: 1080px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Abrir modal
</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div class="modal" id="myModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content modal-long">

      <!-- Modal Header -->
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      </div>

      <!-- Modal body -->
      <div class="modal-body">
        Modal body..
      </div>

      <!-- Modal footer -->
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Não sei se é só aqui, mas o seu modal não está centralizado e ficou cortando um pedaço que ficou para fora da tela....

Comment: @hugocsl porque eu coloquei 1080px para exemplificar o aumento na largura do modal.